# Why can't connect to http service binding on 127.0.0.1 with any ports

Tags: windows, http, go, networking

I wrote a simple http server in Go language as below:

```
http.ListenAndServe(":8888", http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("hello"))
}))
```

When I test it on certain machine runs Windows 7, I found client can't connect to the server.

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 8888
connecting 127.0.0.1… can't open connection to the host.  on port 8888: connect failed. (I translate it from Chinese.)
```

Then I got the results of other test case:

1. ping localhost and 127.0.0.1, successful.
2. telnet localhost 8888, successful.
3. telnet ::1 8888, successful.
4. netstat -ano | find "8888", the server has listened 0.0.0.0:8888 and :::8888.
5. Check the hosts file of OS, it's default configuration (nothing else).
6. Check the Network Adapter, it doesn't open IPV6 adapter.
7. The machine is in domain network.
8. The IP Security Policy is an empty list.
9. When I opened the MMC(Microsoft Management Console), I got a warning like this:
   [message box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yM3Pk.jpg)
   It mean's:
   **Can't find resource "$(string.SiteDiscoveryEnableWMI)" (references in property displayName) . File C:\windows\PolicyDefinitions\inetres.admx, line 64620, row 235**

Anyone can tell me what's going on?

Comment: You could, of course, use any address in the `127.0.0.0/8` block. Try it with a random address in the block to eliminate the possibility that another process is using the `127.0.0.1` address.

Comment: This seems like a problem with your Windows setup, not with your go code. To test this, try running netcat listening on port 8888 and see if you can connect to that with telnet. If you can't, I think you have a problem for Super User, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also, what does localhost resolve to? When you `ping localhost`, it should show something like `Pinging localhost (127.0.0.1) with 32 bytes of data". Is it showing something else?

Comment: Yes, it resolves to ::1 (ipv6) while using `ping localhost` likes the most of  windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

If `XAMPP` is running in your machine, the local server sometimes uses `127.0.0.1` as the default. 
This could be the reason that `ping localhost` is working but telnet is not.

Otherwise check other network services or localservers you have running for any conflicts.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked them. These is no services conflicts with my program and no `XAMPP` running.

Comment: ping is ICMP. It has nothing to do with TCP listening ports (ping will generally work even if there is nothing listening on any port).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does telnet return ping as well?

Comment: @Poseidon, telnet works with TCP connections. Not sure what you mean by "return ping"; ping is the name of a program.

Comment: I meant was, can ping verify IP addresses for telnet as well. I googled and got to know know some interesting things. 
Thanks for your help mate. :)